# Unable to convert string from hidden textbox to double

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my view i pass the value to the controller by doing the following codes

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { id = "postform" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddens" id="xcoordResults" style="width: 250px" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddens" id="ycoordResults" style="width: 250px" />

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Now in my controller then i try to convert pass value to manipulate it later, I recieved an error FormatException was unhandled by usercode. 
The datatype for x_coord in my model is double.

```
  public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<string> hiddens)
        {
            foreach (var item in hiddens)
            {
                //do whatter with item
                model.x_coord =Convert.ToDouble(hiddens.First().ToString());
                model.y_coord = Convert.ToDouble(hiddens.Last().ToString());
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Parse will throw this exception if if cannot understand your string as a double. Add to it that you want the wannabe double to be written using the InvariantCulture that requires a point for decimals. Is this your culture? Did you write the input using a different separator for decimals?

Comment: You don't have values there.

Comment: no values ? in the hiddens ?

Comment: yes, you need values there

Comment: If your values are `double`, then the POSt method should be `public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<double> hiddens)` (not string). But your inputs do not have a `value` attribute so the values are `null`!